# Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed:

Tags: android, appium

I used windows and Eclips.

Bellow class I have Written for the Test :

public class TestApp

{
    AppiumDriver driver;

```
@Test
public void testapp()  throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException
{
    File app =new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\apks\\sigiriya-debug.apk");

      // DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
      DesiredCapabilities capabilities =DesiredCapabilities.android();
      //capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
      capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","google-pixel-FA6C10301834");
      capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
      capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
      capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());


      //  capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.whatsapp");
      //  capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.whatsapp.Main");
      //  dr = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
      driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
     // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


      // clicking
      Thread.sleep(10000);

}
  }
```

When i run the code Apk is installed to my phone.but Test is getting failed with following Error log in the appium console

LogS in Appium :

> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\Users\uwickdi\workspace\Mobile\eselenium.liverPool.testmob\apks\sigiriya-debug.apk","platformVersion":"7.1.1","browserName":"android","platformName":"Android","version":"","deviceName":"google-pixel-FA6C10301834","platform":"ANDROID"}}
>   info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.3 (java 1.5)
>   info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : version, platform
>   info: [debug] No appActivity desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
>   info: [debug] No appPackage desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
>   info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: C:\Users\uwickdi\workspace\Mobile\eselenium.liverPool.testmob\apks\sigiriya-debug.apk
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session 622e973b-f97e-4961-8c0b-c79e13067803
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   info: Java version is: 1.8.0_101
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   info: [debug] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
>   info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
>   info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe
>   info: [debug] Extracting package and launch activity from manifest.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe dump badging C:\Users\uwickdi\workspace\Mobile\eselenium.liverPool.testmob\apks\sigiriya-debug.apk
>   info: [debug] badging package: com.pearsoned.sigiriya
>   info: [debug] badging act: com.pearsoned.sigiriya.view.activity.ActivityDecksView
>   info: [debug] Parsed package and activity are: com.pearsoned.sigiriya/com.pearsoned.sigiriya.view.activity.ActivityDecksView
>   info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
>   info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
>   info: Retrieving device
>   info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: Found device FA6C10301834
>   info: [debug] Setting device id to FA6C10301834
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 shell "echo 'ready'"
>   info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 25
>   info: Device API level is: 25
>   info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 shell "getprop persist.sys.language"
>   info: [debug] Current device persist.sys.language: 
>   info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "C:\Users\uwickdi\workspace\Mobile\eselenium.liverPool.testmob\apks\sigiriya-debug.apk" "C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Temp\com.pearsoned.sigiriya" 
>   info: [debug] Reading strings from converted strings.json
>   info: [debug] Setting language to default
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 push "C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Temp\com.pearsoned.sigiriya\strings.json" /data/local/tmp
>   info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
>   info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe
>   info: [debug] Retrieving process from manifest.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe dump xmltree C:\Users\uwickdi\workspace\Mobile\eselenium.liverPool.testmob\apks\sigiriya-debug.apk AndroidManifest.xml
>   info: [debug] Set app process to: com.pearsoned.sigiriya
>   info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>   info: [debug] Checking app cert for C:\Users\uwickdi\workspace\Mobile\eselenium.liverPool.testmob\apks\sigiriya-debug.apk.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\verify.jar" C:\Users\uwickdi\workspace\Mobile\eselenium.liverPool.testmob\apks\sigiriya-debug.apk
>   info: [debug] App already signed.
>   info: [debug] Zip-aligning C:\Users\uwickdi\workspace\Mobile\eselenium.liverPool.testmob\apks\sigiriya-debug.apk
>   info: [debug] Checking whether zipalign is present
>   info: [debug] Using zipalign from C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\zipalign.exe
>   info: [debug] Zip-aligning apk.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\zipalign.exe -f 4 C:\Users\uwickdi\workspace\Mobile\eselenium.liverPool.testmob\apks\sigiriya-debug.apk C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Temp\117113-3596-12b9r95\appium.tmp
>   info: [debug] MD5 for app is 8ded8f0bf024cef65fdef392e13505bb
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/8ded8f0bf024cef65fdef392e13505bb.apk"
>   info: [debug] Getting install status for com.pearsoned.sigiriya
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 25
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 shell "pm list packages -3 com.pearsoned.sigiriya"
>   info: [debug] App is installed
>   info: App is already installed, resetting app
>   info: [debug] Running fast reset (stop and clear)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 shell "am force-stop com.pearsoned.sigiriya"
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 shell "pm clear com.pearsoned.sigiriya"
>   info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
>   info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 push "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
>   info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
>   info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
>   warn: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>   info: [debug] Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk""
>   Failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
> at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1088:5)
> ```
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 install \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk\"\"\nFailed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]\r\n)","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"cmd":"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 install \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk\"\"","origValue":"Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 install \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk\"\"\nFailed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
>   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s FA6C10301834 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk""
>   Failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]
>
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 21049.722 ms - 1390

Appreciate your help to fix this out. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With the error you are seeing, please confirm that you APK file is unsigned.
Secondly, the error is following

> C:\Users\uwickdi\workspace\Mobile\eselenium.liverPool.testmob\apks\sigiriya-debug.apk
>   C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Temp\117113-3596-12b9r95\appium.tmp
>   info: [debug] MD5 for app is 8ded8f0bf024cef65fdef392e13505bb info:
>   [debug] executing cmd:
>   C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
>   FA6C10301834 shell "ls
>   /data/local/tmp/8ded8f0bf024cef65fdef392e13505bb.apk" info: [debug]
>   Getting install status for com.pearsoned.sigiriya info: [debug]
>   Getting device API level info: [debug] executing cmd:
>   C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
>   FA6C10301834 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk" info: [debug] Device
>   is at API Level 25 info: [debug] executing cmd:
>   C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
>   FA6C10301834 shell "pm list packages -3 com.pearsoned.sigiriya" info:
>   [debug] App is installed info: App is already installed, resetting app
>   info: [debug] Running fast reset (stop and clear) info: [debug]
>   executing cmd:
>   C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
>   FA6C10301834 shell "am force-stop com.pearsoned.sigiriya" info:
>   [debug] executing cmd:
>   C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
>   FA6C10301834 shell "pm clear com.pearsoned.sigiriya" info: [debug]
>   Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724 info: [debug] executing cmd:
>   C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
>   FA6C10301834 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724 info: [debug] Pushing appium
>   bootstrap to device... info: [debug] executing cmd:
>   C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
>   FA6C10301834 push "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar"
>   /data/local/tmp/ info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device... info:
>   [debug] executing cmd:
>   C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
>   FA6C10301834 install "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture info: [debug] Logcat terminated
>   with code null, signal SIGTERM info: [debug] Sent shutdown command,
>   waiting for UiAutomator to stop... warn: UiAutomator did not shut down
>   fast enough, calling it gone info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session info: [debug] Error: Command
>   failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c
>   "C:\Users\uwickdi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
>   FA6C10301834 install "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk""
>   Failed to install C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk:

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install

> io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]

Observe the last two lines in the error message.
Uninstall the original application before running the code. So the app can be re-installed in development mode.

Comment: Before run the class i remove the app from the mobile and APK is unsigned according to the developer.after ran the code apk is installed to the mobile but test is failing.